# Removing older entries from datastore

Tags: java, if-statement, google-cloud-datastore

I am using java to query google cloud datastore in order to find out whether an entry has been there more than one day, and if yes then delete the entry. I have something like this:

```
    if (requestUploaded == true) {

     datastore.delete(row_to_delete);
```

I want to add a logic where:

a) I get the current time.

b) Then check if datastore entry is older than one day, if so, then delete.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation of the issue, I am not aware of any built-in method for creation time in Cloud Datastore entities, so my explanation assumes that you have a `created` property in your entity.

#### Getting current time

You can construct a new `Date` object without any arguments to get the current date and time:

```
import java.util.Date;

Date d = new Date();
```

Optionally, you can use `Timestamp.now()` when creating your Entity, as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#properties_and_value_types):

```
Entity task = Entity.newBuilder(taskKey)
    .set("category", "Personal")
    .set("created", Timestamp.now())
    .set("description",
      StringValue.newBuilder("Learn Cloud Datastore").setExcludeFromIndexes(true).build())
    .build();
```

#### Comparing the entity's creation time to the current date and time

You can leverage the following sample code to fetch all entities where `created` property, which is the date and time that the entity was created, is *less than* the current time, which is defined by `Timestamp.now()`

```
Query<Entity> query = Query.newEntityQueryBuilder()
    .setKind("Person")
    .setFilter(PropertyFilter.lt("created", Timestamp.now()))
    .build();
QueryResults<Entity> results = datastore.run(query);
while (results.hasNext()) {
  Entity currentEntity = results.next();
  System.out.println(currentEntity.getString("name"));
}
```

You can refer to the [PropertyFilter](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-datastore/latest/com/google/cloud/datastore/StructuredQuery.PropertyFilter.html#eq-java.lang.String-com.google.cloud.datastore.Blob-) operator documentation for more details on filtering.

#### Deleting an entity

Lastly, you can [delete](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#deleting_an_entity) an entity by its given key:

```
datastore.delete(taskKey);
```